# Solving constrained equations without optimisation

Tags: r

I need to solve constrained equations in R without optimization.

So there are 10 levels under each of the 5 below categories:

```
Cat  | Avg.Percentage
A    |  33
B    |  75
C    |  80
D    |  95
E    |  110
```

A's 10 levels (x1,x2,...x10) are percentage values and the average of these 10 percentages should be approximately equal to 33 as mentioned in the above table, same notion to be followed for rest of the categories and its levels.

Plus the distribution of percentages within every 10 levels within each of the 5 categories should have the following distribution and bounded constraints:

```
% of levels | min | max
 10%        | 100 | 125
 20%        | 80  | 99
 40%        | 50  | 79
 20%        | 30  | 49
 10%        | 0   | 29
```

How to solve for this in R, without any objective function..

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is infeasble, i.e. there is no solution satisfying the constraints, because if every A value is set to its lower bound then we have the following least possible average:

```
lo <- c(100, 80, 80, 50, 50, 50, 50, 30, 30, 0)
mean(lo)
## [1] 52
```

so it is not possible that the average of the A values is 33.

Similarly the largest possible average is

```
hi <- c(125, 99, 99, 79, 79, 79, 79, 49, 49, 29)
mean(hi)
## [1] 76.6
```

so C, D and E are infeasible as well.

### Change A constraint

If we change the average contraint for A to be 52 instead of 33 then clearly `lo` above is the solution; however, we can get it automaticalLy using lpSolveAPI as shown.

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

lp <- make.lp(0, 10)
set.bounds(lp, lower = c(100, 80, 80, 50, 50, 50, 50, 30, 30, 0),
  upper = c(125, 99, 99, 79, 79, 79, 79, 49, 49, 29))
add.constraint(lp, rep(1, 10)/10, "=", 52)

solve(lp) # 0 means feasible solution found
## [1] 0

get.variables(lp)
## [1] 100  80  80  50  50  50  50  30  30   0
```

### Computing solution for each of A, B, C, D and E

We can iterate over A, B, C, D and E using `sapply` and, as already discussed above, we see that B is the only one with a feasible solution:

```
avg <- c(A = 33, B = 75, C = 80, D = 95, E = 110)
sapply(avg, function(x) {
  lp <- make.lp(0, 10)
  set.bounds(lp, lower = c(100, 80, 80, 50, 50, 50, 50, 30, 30, 0),
    upper = c(125, 99, 99, 79, 79, 79, 79, 49, 49, 29))
  add.constraint(lp, rep(1, 10)/10, "=", x)
  code <- solve(lp)
  v <- get.variables(lp)
  v * if (code > 0) NA else 1
})
```

giving:

```
       A   B  C  D  E
 [1,] NA 125 NA NA NA
 [2,] NA  99 NA NA NA
 [3,] NA  99 NA NA NA
 [4,] NA  79 NA NA NA
 [5,] NA  79 NA NA NA
 [6,] NA  79 NA NA NA
 [7,] NA  79 NA NA NA
 [8,] NA  49 NA NA NA
 [9,] NA  49 NA NA NA
[10,] NA  13 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Sure i understand the minimum can not go to 33, so if we substitute A's avg as 52 that being the least it can go to, and the rest remains the sameas is: 75, 80, 95, 110...

Comment: Thanks a ton for the code G. Grothendieck, unfortunately, when I am running this for the rest: B,C,D,E again the solution becomes infeasible... applying the max values..the max it can reach 76.6...but still its unable to solve for 75 as the constraint.

Comment: Maybe you have made an error in specifying the remaining problems.  I have added code to do it all and B does have a feasible solution.

Comment: Thanks again G. Grothendieck, will need to rework on the problem statement to make it feasible. Really appreciate your help.